# I can't kill process in php script on Ubuntu

Tags: php, linux

i run shell in command line in 1 hours. I want use PHP script to stop it .
I known its $pid is 2000 by use getmypid();

I used PHP script as: `exec("kill 2000");exec("kill -KILL 2000"); exec("kill -9 2000"); posix_kill(2000,9);` but can't kill it.

If in terminal, i simple use `~$ kill 2000` .But can't with php script .

Comment: sorry, i don't know this. Addtional info , shell run php script

Answer (score 2):

If you're running PHP with safe mode on you'll have to change safe_mode_exec_dir to include the dirs of the kill binaries, you'll also have to use "su -c" to kill processes not owned as yourself. It also depends on whether exec() is in the list of disabled_functions in php.ini.

Comment: Use
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
    $output = exec("su -c kill 2000");
    echo $output;
?>

and see if an error appears.

Comment: I change to var_dump($output) ; return string '' (length=0). No warning, error.

Answer (score 0):

Check your safe mode configuration in `php.ini`. See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.functions.php) for more information .