# Use PHP to kill process initiated by LaunchDaemon

Tags: php, process, kill

I would like to use PHP to kill a process initiated by a LaunchDaemon.

I have my script, I'm grabbing and storing the pid - using getmypid() - using a table, and then referring back to that to kill the process, but I'm stuck because:

```
exec('sudo kill 12345');
```

won't work.

Is it possible to use sudo in php exec? Are there any other ways to kill a process using PHP that doesn't use the proc funcctions, or would proc_terminate and proc_open be something I should look into?

I have seen this - there is no answer so maybe it is not possible: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971231/i-cant-kill-process-in-php-script-on-ubuntu)

Comment: Good question, next question.

Comment: what is that supposed to mean.

Comment: That information is missing to answer your question if it's hopeless (which AFAIK is not a programming question) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you seen existing material like [*How to call shell script from php that requires SUDO?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3166123/367456) we have on site?

Comment: No. I searched and searched and didn't see that one. Thank you! This is all much more helpful than your first comment. Thanks guy.

Comment: Writing "Is it possible to use sudo in php exec?" was much more helpful to find that other question than the hopeless sentence :)